# How can I prevent my friends, especially "Family", from being suggested to other friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, friend-list

I'm seriously considering a situation where people on my friend list wouldn't be suggested to anyone else on my friend list (especially, someone with lower count) to **"Add as a Friend"** suggestion over Facebook.

If I cannot make it happen for everyone, at least is there any way to prevent people listed under "Family" from getting suggested to other friends?

Answer (score 2):

afaik, what you've asked is not directly possible

#### but this is possible :

1. go to `https://www.facebook.com/{your username}/friends`
2. click edit icon , click **edit privacy**
3. change **Friend List** to **only me**

**pro** - you can hide being displayed as mutual friend so people won't know if the person is your friend or not

**con** - people from your friend *might* still end up being suggested...but now you won't be seen in as mutual friend

Comment: I already have done this a year before, but its not helpful as once I faced a situation in which people listed under Family received Friend-Request from some other friend(who has no other mutual friend but me with my Family member).

Comment: yes it will still be shown as "1 mutual friend" but details of that guy (you) won't be shown now...

Comment: That is unfortunately not true (anymore). I got "only me" selected yet my face is displayed inside the suggested profile. Very annoying.